# Recover svn from directory backup after server failure

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, code-migration

The machine hosting our svn server failed. We were able to recover the `C:\Repositories\` directory. How do we migrate this to a new host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just install svn as normal on the new server, copy the Repositories directory to the new server, and point svn at the directorys containing your repositorys.

Comment: This appears to have worked. But if this is so simple, why are the instructions for migrating when the source and target host are alive slightly more complicated? (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)

Comment: Those instructions assume your backing up a live repository and want users to have access durring the backup. Your repository isn't live so you don't have to worry about users accessing it while backup/restore is taking place.