# Recovering a SVN Repository with out a dump file

Tags: svn, recovery

I have an old repository that I have no dump file for. I do have the complete repository, though, and am hoping that I can get it running on a new system.

I tried reading [Recover svn from directory backup after server failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610652/recover-svn-from-directory-backup-after-server-failure) which gives me hope, but doesn't seem to have worked for me. Whenever I point TortoiseSVN or svnadmin at the repository folder to examine it, it reports "No such revision 1" despite there being 130 revs in the db folder.

Any advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Tony

Comment: At which exact URL did you point TortoiseSVN?

Comment: to the repository folder name - C:\Path-to-repository\

Comment: to confirm... the repo is on my hard drive, so it's file:///C:/path-to-repo/

Comment: Apparently you *don't* have the complete repository. The file for revision 1 is missing.

Comment: So does that mean I'm doomed then?

Answer (score 1):

you can always create a dumpfile by using

```
svnadmin dump [PATH_TO_REPO] > newDump.dmp
```

However, I doubt you will succeed as the error message indicates that there is simply something wrong with your revisions.

Is there an file called "1" insinde the *db/revs*-dir?

Comment: Good spot. There is no rev 1.

Do you know if there's a way to patch this up? On a wild hunch I just duplicated 0 and renamed as 1 but no dice - as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://www.robgonda.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/10/19/SVN-PROPFIND-request-failed--No-Such-Revision) mentions the error message, abide with a different revision number.

> I noticed that the error claimed that
>   revision 296 did not exist and indeed,
>   when I opened the db/revs folder it
>   only went up to 295. With a completely
>   wild guess, I opened the /current file
>   and noticed that it had the 296
>   revision number on it, so I assumed
>   this is the pointer to the latest
>   revision, but the data never made it
>   to the server... I modified the number
>   to 295 and everything immediately
>   started working.

That's a bit of hack though.

Comment: Thanks a million for that. I've tried moving the pointer to a couple of other places, but no luck...