# Pointing svnserve to an existing Repository Directory - (Windows)

Tags: svn, restore, recovery

I use SVN under Windows for personal projects. My harddrive crashed recently but, fortunately, I have a backup folder with my repository.

I do not have a dump file. (So cannot use the recommended method: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate )

How do I point a new installation of svnserve to that backup folder.

I found these related posts:

One talks about "pointing" the new SVN server to the directory, but does not mention how:
[Recover svn from directory backup after server failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610652/recover-svn-from-directory-backup-after-server-failure)

The closest to an answer I need suggests that I should create a dump file against that folder using svnadmin: [Recovering a SVN Repository with out a dump file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147428/recovering-a-svn-repository-with-out-a-dump-file?rq=1). If that would solve it, do I look for the exact svn version that the repository was created in (cant remember) or can I use the fresh install, which may be a few versions ahead of the old one?

Apologies in advance if the answer exists, I failed to find it.

Thanks!

tino

Comment: Why do you use svnserve? Any special reason for that?

Comment: Do you have .svn folders in your backup folder?

Comment: @bahrep No special reason. I run it as a windows service. I am open to any SVN solution that will help me recover.

Comment: @PM It is the repository folder, not a working folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fortunate that I had a copy of the installer I used to create the SVN repository I was making use of before my harddrive crashed. So this is what I did:

1. Installed that version
2. List item
3. Relocated repository to point to my backup copy
4. Had UUID issues which I resolved thanks to [some posts](https://superuser.com/questions/229983/how-to-change-subversion-working-copy-uuid) here and the [svn red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html)
5. Had some missing revision issues that I resolved with the help of a number of resources
6. Created an SVN service(my preferred setup for svn:// browsing), pointing to the restored repository
7. Installed Tortoise SVN and performed an upgrade
8. Upgraded the latest working folder
9. Checked-out the latest revision to a new working folder (my new clean version)
10. Copied files from the upgraded working folder (in item 8.) to the new working folder (in item 9)
11. Checked in everything from new working folder
12. Now up and running :)

Migrating to an alternative VCS soon. Unfortunately, I'm only allowed 2 links, will update once I get more points.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/),
2. Put your existing repository under `C:\Repositories\` 
   (or to other repositories root folder you've chosen during the install process),
3. Start VisualSVN Server Manager and configure access rights to the repository if required.
   Your repository will be available at the URL `https://<hostname>/svn/<repository-name>`

If your repository is old you may want to upgrade it by running it through [the dump-load cycle](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#dumpload).

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late response.

Tried using VisualSVN, it did not solve my problem. Because of the different SVN versions(mine very old), it through an svn: cant open file format error.